# Conditional expectations by conditioning on functions of random variables

Tags: conditional-probability, expected-value, conditional-expectation

I have conjectured the following:

Let $f:\mathbb{R}\supseteq A \rightarrow B \subseteq \mathbb{R}$ be an injective function. Let $X$ be a random variable with support $A$ and $Y$ be some random variable that is not independent from $X$. Then, $$E[Y | X=x]=E[Y|f(X)=f(x)].$$

Is that correct? If it is correct, is there any "weaker" assumption (weaker than $f$ being injective) that would make this true?

Thanks.

Comment: You definitely need *stronger* conditions.  At a minimum, $f$ must be measurable for $f(X)$ even to be a random variable.

Comment: Also asked simultaneously on [math.SE](http://math.stackexchange.com/q/606142/15941)

Comment: Since $f$ is injective, conditioning on $X$ is equivalent to conditioning on $f(X)$. I believe this is a necessary and sufficient condition. This should be clear intuitively, since if you know $f(X)$ then the only way to ascertain the value of $X$ is for $f$ to be injective.

Comment: @Whuber - Is there any need to mention that $f$ is measurable? I mean, you are right - $f$ needs to be measurable, but I don't think that's really the kind of answer he had in mind.

Comment: @Christian:  Whey do you think it is a necessary condition?  Suppose for example that $f$ was not injective but that given $f(X)=f(x)$ you had $Y$ conditionally independent of $X$.

Comment: Well I do not think that is possible...

Comment: @Christian: Or take for example $X$ symmetrically distributed about $0$, $f(x) = x^2$ and $Y=|X|$.  Then

Comment: But that function is not injective...

Comment: @Christian: *Exactly!* (This is why Henry has mentioned it.)

Comment: Ok so it's obviously a sufficient but not necessary condition. @Cardinal - Any ideas how to get a necessary condition?

Comment: Can the measurability concern be circumvented by instead talking about $\mathbb{E}(Y|X \in f^{-1}(f(x)))$, so that it's only necessary that each point has a measurable pre-image under $f$ ?

Answer (score 2):

#### Injectivity is sufficient (so long as your function is measurable)

Let's assume that $f$ is a measureable function, so that all relevant random variables and events are well-defined.  Now, to give this some more structure, suppose we are working in a probability space $(\Omega, \mathscr{S}, \mathbb{P})$ so that $X: \Omega \rightarrow A$ is your conditioning random variable of interest.  Since $f$ is an injective function it has a left-inverse $g: B \rightarrow A$ (i.e., $g(f(x))=x$ for all $x \in A$).  Thus, for all $x \in A$ you have the following event equivalence:

$$\begin{align}
\{ \omega \in \Omega | f(X(\omega)) = f(x) \} 
&= \{ \omega \in \Omega | g(f(X(\omega))) = g(f(x)) \} \\[6pt]
&= \{ \omega \in \Omega | X(\omega) = (x) \} \\[6pt]
\end{align}$$

This means that conditioning on $f(X)=x$ is equivalent to conditioning on $X=x$.  Thus, so long as $f$ is measureable, that should be enough to obtain equivalence of the conditional expectations.  (Proof of this is a bit more involved, since you need to establish this via the Radon-Nikodym form for conditional expectation, or via theorems about sigma-fields; that should not be especially difficult.)

Comment: Is the right-inverse $g$ measurable? I would guess it is, but that is not entirely trivial to prove.

Answer (score 0):

if $Z=f(X)$ and $f$ is injective function so $$\sigma(Z)=\sigma(X)$$

since $Z=f(X)$ so $$\sigma(Z) \subset \sigma(X)$$

and because $f$ is injective so $X=f^{-1}(Z)=g(Z)$ so  $$\sigma(X) \subset \sigma(Z)$$

so $\sigma(Z)=\sigma(X)$ or $\sigma(f(X))=\sigma(X)$

now $$E(Y|X)=E(Y|\sigma(X))=E(Y|\sigma(f(X)))=E(Y|f(X))$$

Comment: Injective functions are not automatically measurable.  For a counterexample, construct an $f$ that maps a non-measurable set (which will be uncountable) injectively into an interval (which also is uncountable but is measurable).

Comment: @whuber :i mean a injective function of a random variable is a random variable! is it true?

Comment: No, as a general proposition that is false, as the counterexample shows.

Comment: I removed that mistake .tnx

Comment: when invective function is measurable?

Comment: Right: when $f$ is an injective *measurable* function, clearly the result holds.  (This is the "sufficient condition" in [Christian's comment](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/79638/conditional-expectations-by-conditioning-on-functions-of-random-variables/450438?noredirect=1#comment156169_79638).) The outstanding question is what would be a *necessary* condition for the result to hold.

Comment: I think if "f"  be monotone or continues  the results hold! is it true?!

Comment: Continuous functions are measurable.  Monotonic functions are not necessarily measurable.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming $f$ is measurable I think the weakest condition is:

- Whenever $\mathbb{E}(Y|X=x_1) \ne \mathbb{E}(Y|X=x_2), f(x_1) \ne f(x_2)$.